# Why can't one book a Greyhound bus from the United States to Mexico departing within the next 3 days?

Tags: usa, international-travel, buses, mexico, greyhound

While one may book a Greyhound bus ticket on the same day for a trip within the United States, It  seems that one cannot book a Greyhound bus from the United States to Mexico departing within the next 3 days (I use [this link](https://www.greyhound.com/en-us/bus-from-san-diego-1-to-tijuana) for the bookings). Why? Is that because Greyhound has to declare the passenger list to the US CBP or some other US agency ahead of time? Check the passenger travel document ahead of departure? Some other reasons?

Eg, on Sunday February 19, 5 PM PT, one can't book any of the following path before Wednesday February 22.

- Austin to Monterey: [no trips within the next 3 days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcL5C.png).
- El Paso to Ciudad de Juarez: [no trips within the next 3 days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERybd.png).
- [San Diego to Tijuana](https://www.greyhound.com/en-us/bus-from-san-diego-1-to-tijuana): [no trips within the next 3 days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCXeu.png).

The last two paths are especially very frequent with ~6 buses available each day.

Comment: Even if Greyhound has to send passenger data to CBP I imagine they would have a facility to make updates and other corrections up to the last minute, as airlines have.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm not sure the premise is correct.

The [SD > Tijuana Greyhound page you cite](https://www.greyhound.com/en-us/bus-from-san-diego-1-to-tijuana) specifically says "If your travel is within the next three days, book at [this other Greyhound page](https://www.greyhound.com/en)."

I went to the other page, which took my booking for 2/21/23 easily all the way up to asking for my payment info. I didn't go further.

Comment: this is correct; apparently Greyhound is rolling out a new booking platform of some sort, and I get redirected to and from it for trips on a variety of routes, not all of which cross borders

Comment: Thanks, interestingly, on your link ([greyhound.com/en](https://www.greyhound.com/en)), one can't book more than 3 days ahead and prices are 5 times higher for SD->TJ (but only 1.5 more expensive for El Paso to Ciudad de Juarez:). That Greyhound website is a mess.